# Jenkins 1.616 over glassfish 4 using apache as proxy - Unable to logout

Tags: apache, jenkins, proxy, glassfish

I'm using Apache as a proxy for jenkins 1.616 on glassfish 4 and I'm unable to logout while using the proxy. But this is not the case with direct access.

Apache proxy options:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.server
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

    ProxyPass / http://GF.SERVER:8088/ nocanon
    ProxyPassReverse / http://GF.SERVER:8088/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://example.server/

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Source: [Running Jenkins behind Apache](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Apache)

I have also tried setting the below options for JVM:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=some.proxy.host
-Dhttp.proxyPort=1234
-Dhttps.proxyHost=some.otherorsame.host
-Dhttps.proxyPort=2345
```

Source: [JenkinsBehindProxy](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JenkinsBehindProxy)

All the setup but of no use.

Answer (score 0):

I have a global option setup as `ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"`.

This was causing the issue.
I put `ExpiresDefault "now"` in my virtual host setting and this is resolved.